# Connect RabbitMQ in a external host - PHP

Tags: php, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm trying connect in a external host with `rabbitMq` but i have problens.
the data that I have are:

```
HOST: A IP from HOST - OK
PORT: PORT from HOST - OK
CHANNEL: TESTE.TESTE
GENERAL: TESTE
```

the code to connect is:

```
$connection = new AMQPConnection('HOST', PORT, '', '');
$channel = $connection->channel();
```

The question is: How to use the channel ?
The error is:

```
Uncaught exception 'PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException' with message 'Error Connecting to server(110): Connection timed out.
```

Sorry the english.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a user and a password to connect? Also RabbitMQ forbids connecting as guest:guest from a remote host. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html